# Saving webpage as PDF using Selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to download the Page speed report from
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/.
Since it does not have a "Print" option, I need to save the webpage using selenium and java.
What would be my options here?

Answer (score 1):

Once you are one the Page speed page, you can use the below code to get the innerHTML.

```
String htmlContent = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
System.out.println(htmlContent);
```

If you want to save this string to PDF file use the below mentioned library :

https://pdfbox.apache.org/

Once you have the mentioned library in your project. You can use the below code:

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
try {
  doc.load("your pdf file path");  
  // Write text at position (100, 100) on page 1
  doc.writeText(
    htmlContent,
    100, // x-coordinate
    50); // y-coordinate
   
  doc.save("your pdf file path");
  doc.close();
} catch (IOException | PdfException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Read this line `I need to save the webpage using selenium and java.`

Comment: @Prophet : anyway updated the code since it is there in OP heading.

Comment: I see. As I understand he wants to save it in PDF format with Selenium. Actually it's possible with Control + P

Comment: I see, nice solution!

Comment: @Prophet : Once you do CTRL + P you will loose Selenium control. But it might be worth trying I feel :)

Comment: I know, it's possible to continue with Robot or some other library to press a OS dialog buttons. On the other hand it's possibly that your solution is better. That's why I upvoted it :)

Comment: yeah robot or AutoIT (windows) would definitely work, but they have not been consistent.

Comment: For AutoIt,  if you are CTRL+P, some times it wont work if the machine is locked while running the scripts, else it wont work and use delays accordingly in the auto it script. In this way, you can make the script consistent